# Riemannian Manifolds with $n(n+1)/2$ dimensional symmetry group

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Given a $n$-dimensional connected Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, its symmetry group $G$ can be considered as a subbundle of orthonormal frame bundle of $M$ (which I call $F_OM$), yielding: $$\dim G\le \dim F_OM=\dim M +\dim O(n)={n+n(n-1)\over 2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ (Here the embedding $\phi:G \hookrightarrow F_OM$ is defined by singling out an arbitrary point $p \in M$ and orthonormal frame $(v_1,...,v_n) \in F_{O,p} M$ and defining $\phi: g \mapsto (gp,g_*v_1,...,g_*v_n)$. However, it takes some work to verify that this map is indeed injective.)

These considerations made me wonder which manifolds have a maximally large symmetry group, i.e. which $M$ do satisfy $\dim G= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Of, course $\Bbb R^n,\Bbb S^n$ and $\Bbb H^n$ have got this property, but are there any other exotic examples?

(Some thoughts of mine on this problem: One can see that $M$ is homogenuous and isotropic. Each stabiliser of a point has to be isomorphic to either $SO(n)$ or $O(n)$. In particular, $M$ has constant curvature, which implies that $M$ has to be one of $\Bbb R^n,\Bbb S^n$ and $\Bbb H^n$ if $M$ is complete and simply-connected.)

Comment: Also, $RP^n$, but I think that's it.

Comment: @studiosus: Better stick to the simply connected case. There are all sorts of quotient manifolds.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Yes, there are, but the projective space is the only one whose fundamental group is central in the full isometry group of the universal cover. In fact, these four examples form the complete list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete list of such manifolds consists of the three simply connected ones as well as the real-projective space with the constant curvature metric. Here is why. Suppose that $\pi$ is the group of covering transformations of M, identified with the subgroup of the full group G of isometries of the universal cover of M. Then $\pi$ commutes with the connected component $G_o$ of identity in G, otherwise the isometry group of M has dimension less than G. Now, you just have to do case by case analysis. You see that only in the spherical case the group $G_o$ has nontrivial centralizer in G, namely, it is the center of G, generated by the antipodal map. This gives us the projective space.

Answer (score 2):

See [Kobayashi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PY4HUA) for the definitive answers to this question and more.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but could you please provide the precise statement of the relevant theorems in the book and maybe also a short comment on how these results are established?

Comment: @Dominik: The is a very nice book but it will not tell you anything about the question that you do not already know. Still, if you are interested in automorphism groups of various geometric structures, you should take a look at it.

Comment: @Dominik: Your request is perfectly reasonable, but I've lent my copy to a graduate student and don't have easy access at the moment :(