# Manifold with largest symmetry group

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Is there any $n$-dimensional (smooth) manifold $M_{0}$ which has **largest** symmetry  group, i.e. for any $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, $Sym(M)$ can be embedded in $Sym(M_{0})$? Intuitively, if it exists, I think sphere or whole euclidean space will give answer (because it looks highly symmetric), but I don't know how to show or even such manifold exists. 
Is there any known results with more specific conditions? (specific $n$, compact manifold, complex manifold, Riemannian manifold (with isometry group), ...) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maximal, yes. Maximum, no. At least if you interpret the symmetry group the usual way. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587189/riemannian-manifolds-with-nn1-2-dimensional-symmetry-group

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! I have another question, why it is not maximum? Can you give me any example of $n$-manifold which have symmetric group cannot be embedded in $Sym(S^{n})$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example? The group $SO(n+1)$ of symmetries of $\mathbb{S}^n$ is compact, but the Euclidean group is non-compact.

Comment: @WillieWong Then, is there any example for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? I should have ask both..

Comment: $\mathbb{S}^n$, for example? The Euclidean group and $SO(n+1)$ are connected Lie groups of the same dimension.